# How to read many files have a specific format in python

Tags: python-3.x, file

I am a little bit confused in how to read all lines in many files where the file names have format from "datalog.txt.98" to "datalog.txt.120".

This is my code:

```
import json

file = "datalog.txt."      

i = 97

for line in file:

    i+=1

    f = open (line + str (i),'r')

    for row in f:

        print (row)
```

Here, you will find an example of one line in one of those files:

[image]

I need really to your help

Comment: Could you please help me in reading all lines in all files which have not format?

Comment: Your files are JSON files. You'd better use a JSON reader from the namesake module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest using a loop for opening multiple files with different formats.

To better understand this project I would recommend researching the following topics

- for loops,
- String manipulation,
- Opening a file and reading its content,
- List manipulation,
- String parsing.

[This](https://developers.google.com/edu/python/) is one of my favourite beginner guides.

To set the parameters of the integers at the end of the file name I would look into python for loops.

I think this is what you are trying to do

```
# create a list to store all your file content
files_content = []

# the prefix is of type string
filename_prefix = "datalog.txt." 

# loop from 0 to 13
for i in range(0,14):
    # make the filename variable with the prefix and
    # the integer i which you need to convert to a string type
    filename = filename_prefix + str(i)

    # open the file read all the lines to a variable 
     with open(filename) as f:
        content = f.readlines()
    
    # append the file content to the files_content list
    files_content.append(content)
```

To get rid of white space from file parsing add the missing line

```
content = [x.strip() for x in content]
files_content.append(content)
```

Here's an example of printing out files_content

```
for file in files_content:
    print(file)
```

Comment: I got this error  File "<ipython-input-58-772d29536543>", line 15
    with open(filename) as f:
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent

Comment: I am trying to read all, files which have formats from "datalog.txt.98" to "datalog.txt.120"

Comment: I recommend learning the basics of python to solve this problem. If I were to give you the answer that might help you in the short term but it'll be more valuable to figure it out yourself.